# Error when getting in to MYSQL from terminal

Tags: mysql, mac-os-x

I get this error message:

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

when i try to enter mysql from terminal (Macos).

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this before. Have you set you root password properly? Before trying to login, set the password and ensure that permissions allow root from localhost to login.

Last I remembered, if you have not explicitly allowed root from localhost to login or some sort of wildcard that covers that, you will get such an error.